# how to remove www using htacces

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I want redirct https without www,

i have tried below code,

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.subdomain.doamin\.io [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://ubdomain.doamin.io/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Try the code again with fewer typos? (e.g not redirecting **subdomain**.doamin to **ubdomain**.doamin) Or update the question if it's just incorrect here.

Comment: Your question does not make clear whether you want an alternative to using a .htaccess file, or whether yours doesn't work. If the latter is the case always describe what it does wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code,it will redirect to https without www and works for me

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```